# How can I pass a value from one class to another using onkeypress?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to build a game where a ship should shoot some stuff, I am trying to get the ship position and pass it to the function that generate the shot, but I can't do this, I tried the below methods:

ship.py

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.ship = Turtle(shape='turtle')
    self.ship.penup()
    self.ship.color('white')
    self.ship.goto(0, -250)
    self.ship.left(90)
    self.x = self.ship.xcor()

def get_pos(self):
    return self.x
```

shoot.py

```
def shoot_now(self, pos):
        print(pos)
```

First try with ship.get_pos()
main.py

```
screen.onkeypress(functools.partial(shots.shoot_now, ship.get_pos()), 'space')
```

Second try wuth ship.get_pos

```
screen.onkeypress(functools.partial(shots.shoot_now, ship.get_pos), 'space')
```

The first one results in a lot of 0 and the second one result something like that:

```
<bound method Ship.get_pos of <ship.Ship object at 0x000001F05339A520>>
```

I know that the function get_pos is working because everytime I run it alone it prints the right position, but when I try to use the onkeypress to pass the value to shoot.py it does not work.

Does someone know a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're locking in the ship's position once, when `onkeypress()` is called, and all subsequent key presses are using that original value.

Besides the ship's *position*, you also need to know the ship's *heading* when a bullet is fired.  To simplify programming, I'd have both the ship and bullet *be* turtles, rather than *contain* turtles, though either will work.

If you want to keep the bullet's motion from locking out the ship's motion, you're going to need a timer.  Here's a minimal implementation that gets you a single moving bullet that doesn't freeze the ship's motion:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Bullet(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.hideturtle()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.shapesize(0.25)
        self.penup()

        self.origin = (0, 0)

    def fire(self, origin, heading):
        self.origin = origin

        self.setheading(heading)
        self.setposition(origin)
        self.showturtle()
        self.move()

    def move(self):
        if self.distance(self.origin) < 500:
            self.forward(5)
            screen.ontimer(self.move, 5)
        else:
            self.hideturtle()

class Ship(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.shape('triangle')
        self.penup()
        self.sety(-250)
        self.left(90)

    def shoot_now(self):
        if not bullet.isvisible():
            bullet.fire(self.position(), self.heading())

screen = Screen()
bullet = Bullet()
ship = Ship()

screen.onkeypress(lambda: ship.right(5), 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(lambda: ship.left(5), 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(ship.shoot_now, 'space')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

To extend this to multiple live bullets, you can keep a list of inactive bullets, pull from it when you fire, add back to it when the bullet is spent.  This also gives you control over the number of bullets in play.

Comment: I didn't need the heading because the ship is always pointing to a specific region, besides that thank you for sharing your idea, it gave me some insight of how to adapt my code.